# Is there a way to tell a replicate function how long to make the string?

Tags: r, dplyr, replicate

I'm using RStudio and am trying to compute a new column that contains a set of repeated letters with the value of those numbers taken from a corresponding column.

E.g., I have the data in ColA below, but would like to create ColB:

`ColA <- c(1, 4, 6)`

I would like ColB to be like this:

| ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | p |
| 4 | pppp |
| 6 | pppppp |

I have been trying to use replicate but I can't work out how to make the frequency/length of the string equal to the value of the corresponding ColA.

`df %>% mutate(ColB = rep("p", length.out = df$ColA, nrow(df)))`

I can't seem to get rep to accept another value other than the number of rows of data - is there a way to also feed in the string length?

Any help greatly appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `base R` solution:

```
df$ColB <- strrep("p", df$ColA)

  ColA   ColB
1    1      p
2    4   pppp
3    6 pppppp
```

You can also use this with `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(ColB = strrep("p", ColA))
```

Comment: Nice answer! I always forgot `strrep`. Upvoted your answer!

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding - coincidentally had to do something similar recently. Very helpful function!